# C++ Boost thread library pulls in the whole development environment

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu, boost-thread, apt

I am using boost-thread in my application. When I deploy this application on a client machine (running Ubuntu 11.10), I need to make sure that libboost_thread.so is available on the machine. However, when I run "apt-get install libboost-thread1.46," it seems to pull in the whole development enviornment (libgcc, libbost1.46-dev, etc.). This machine needs just the runtime environment, not the development environment. I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such package exception: The package "libboost-thread1.46" does not exist on Ubuntu, is treated by `apt-get` as a regular expression, and the development package *also* matches the expression. The two candidate packages are named `libboost-thread1.46-dev` and [libboost-thread1.46.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-thread1.46.1), where the latter is the package you want. It depends only on three libraries (libgcc, libc, libstdc++), *all of which you need to deploy anyway* because your program and libboost-thread link against them.

So, deploy by installing `libboost-thread1.46.1` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can build individual requirements yourself by download the boost tar and using the `bjam` build tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could link statically against boost.

Comment: I didn't know that. How do I link statically?

Comment: `-Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_foo -Wl,-Bdynamic` should to the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) and copy the necessary files into your own source tree. I personally have the headers installed on my system and just added the source files to my project (`once.cpp`, `thread.cpp`, `timeconv.inl`, `tss_null.cpp` on Linux).

Comment: This looks like a good option. I will look into it. Thank you.